# FCM token is always the same for JS app

Tags: javascript, firebase-authentication, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am working to implement Firebase Cloud Messaging in a Javascript App. I followed different tutorials and now the web app is receiving the notification with the expected content (I'm using Curl to send content). The only thing that I don't understand is that the FCM token is always the same. I would have thought that there was a way to generate an FCM token for each user I wanted to pass to my backend so that the backend could notify only that user using the FCM token.

What am I missing?

The documentation doesn't seem to clear...

Thanks

Comment: There is one token per device/user, you might be mistaken with the implementation.

Comment: what do you mean? It's a web app so if two people are sharing the same laptop and using Chrome (same Windows user), they will have the same token?

Comment: The FCM token identifies an application instance. If two users are sharing the same browser **profile**, they will have the same token. If that's unwanted, you should force a refresh of the token when the user signs in/out.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like I've found a solution using firebase JS SDK v. 4.4.0. Unfortunately `getToken(true)` which was the way to go is no longer supported, therefore the only option is to:

1. get a token
2. delete that token
3. get a token again

   ```
   this.messaging.getToken()
       .then(oldToken => {
           this.messaging.deleteToken(oldToken).then(() => {
               this.messaging.getToken().then(newToken => {
                   this.updateToken(newToken)
               })
           })
       })
   ```

not the easiest SDK...